# How to disable deep linking after enabling it in android?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have enabled deep linking in android by following steps mentioned here:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

From business there can be situation we have to disable deep linking.
so how can we achieve this with out updating app?
can we make it configurable?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the corresponding code and update your app on the Play Store...

Comment: Thanks for replying but we don't want to update the app ,value is configured on server for enable and disable of deep link on basis of that app should work.

Comment: Then you can't. Deeplinks are handled at the system level, and not the app level.

Comment: What you could do instead is, when starting the app, if you don't want to handle the deeplink, redirect the user to the browser.

Comment: You have to have one API which will return boolean to enable or disable the DeepLinking. Based on business, server has to return the response. You need to hit the API on your deep linking Activity and redirect the user to browser in case of disabled deep linking and kill your activity.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do it as it's handled on the OS level. Even if you redirect users to the browser and they click on any link that you registered as deep-link it will open your app again.